# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError while trying to connect to MySQL database using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using PyMySQL driver and Flask-SQLAlchemy. However, I am getting the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I am able to connect to the database using just PyMySQL. Here is my Flask API code.

```
from flask import Flask, json, Response
import pymysql
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/dbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
CORS(app, resources=r'/*')

class SomeTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(255), nullable=False)

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    my_list = SomeTable.query.all()
    data = json.dumps(my_list)
    flaskResponse = Response(data)
    flaskResponse.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    flaskResponse.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = ORIGIN
    return flaskResponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am not sure where am I going wrong. I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue.

Comment: This looks like your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` is being completely ignored because it's trying to use `root` instead of username. `mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/dbname` is this string exactly what you're using? Or did you sanitizeit?

Comment: When I run the code as you posted it I get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")` because obviously I'm not running a mysql server reachable at `host`.

Comment: Host is actually localhost. Username is root and password is the actual password of my MySQL server running on my PC.

Comment: Well that error is coming from mysql server. So your credentials must be wrong

Comment: But I am able to connect to MySQL server using PyMySQL directly. I do not understand why am I getting an error when I use the same credentials with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Just throwing it out there: could there be multiple versions of MySQL running on same machine?

Comment: It's a new machine and I remember installing MySQL only once. Hence, I don't think there are multiple versions of MySQL running on my machine.

Comment: For the sake of clarity my connection string is app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost/dbname' where password and dbname are replaced by their actual values.

Comment: @RupamKundu are you able to connect to it via workbench or some other sql client?